# Study guide (and...) for "Intermediate Microeconomics with Calculus" by Varian

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, self-study, books

I have been googling study guides, solution manuals and other helpful material made by professors. But I have not found anything useful.

Q: Do you guys know anything that will make the book easier and faster to digest?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will be better than going through the textbook. Lecture's slides can be beneficial, you can google newer versions or access older here: http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~mirobins/econ212.html. I also used notes done by Łukasz Woźny, from SGH: http://web.sgh.waw.pl/lwozny/LectureNotes.pdf - they are not entirely based on Varian's textbook but might be helpful as well. There is also an Instructor’s Manual to each of Varian's books where he points out what is the most important from each chapter - also you should be able to find one online, and can also be quite helpful if you want to consume his textbook faster.

Comment: I found some Instructor’s Manual but none of them where meant to be used with the calculus edition.

Comment: On the internet versions it might not be specified - usually there is Varian's comment what to take into consideration when running calculus-based course. Check it. I have 2014 version of instructor's manual that I believe would be compatible.

Comment: Do you mind sharing? I can give my email address.

Comment: Google ISBN 978-0-393-93676-6, the result containing "Hal R. Varian" should be the correct one.

Comment: I know about this one. Unfortunately, It's not compatible with "Intermediate Microeconomics with Calculus" 1e, by Varian.

Comment: It should be compatible with, as the cover states: https://www.amazon.com/Intermediate-Microeconomics-Instructors-Manual-Varian/dp/0393936767. Oh not sure about editions though... But from my experience they do not add much in newer editions tbh. ;) You can still try to use it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I think it's a bit odd. The problem in the calculus version did not correspond to the answers in the Instructor’s Manual. But, yeah, I will see if it's any use.